# Erro SSL (Modulo requests Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, ssl

Estou desenvolvendo um programa para a captura de artigos no site da Scielo, o programa estava funcionando perfeitamente, porém hoje pela manhã quando fui executa-lo o seguinte erro me foi apresentado:

> PS C:\Users\Vinicius> & C:/Users/Vinicius/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/Vinicius/Desktop/Estagio2.0/Estagio2.0/main.py
> Digite qual o link do resumo? https://www.scielo.br/j/icse/a/jj7Rwgd4DwgBB5WrwhY4Bbb/abstract/?lang=pt
> C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1013: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'www.scielo.br'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
> warnings.warn(
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(
> File "C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
> self._validate_conn(conn)
> File "C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in *validate_conn
> conn.connect()
> File "C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 411, in connect
> self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
> File "C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
> ssl_sock = *ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
> File "C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
> return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
> File "C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
> return self.sslsocket_class._create(
> File "C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
> self.do_handshake()
> File "C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake()
> ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired
> (_ssl.c:1129)

Acredito que o erro esteja se originando no seguinte trecho do código:

```
while True:
    try:
        requests.get(link, verify = False) 
    except:  
        link = input('Link fora do ar ou invalido, tente novamente: ')
    else:
        break
```

(Faz parte de uma função que retorna se o link está ou não on).
Já tentei com e sem o "Verify"

Answer (score 0):

Depois de pesquisas consegui uma resposta paliativa para o problema(pois desisntala os certificados SSL mais recentes e usa antigos), ela é:

```
 pip uninstall -y certifi
 pip install certifi==2015.04.28
```